# How can I configure an Azure Function to work with dynamic configuration using Azure App Configuration?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, .net-6.0, azure-app-configuration

I'm trying to write an Azure Function that works as a multi-tenant. When a clientId comes from the clients as a parameter, I need to fetch its configuration from Azure App Configuration using labels.

Let me explain in a pseudo code;

I'm using .Net 6 Azure Function Isolated.
I made configuration in Program.cs like in the below code;

```
new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration(builder =>
{
    string cs = "connection-string"; //which is actually comes from environment veriable
    builder.AddAzureAppConfiguration(options =>
    {
        options.Connect(cs);
        //options.Select(KeyFilter.Any, Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ClientId")); //It works that way, but I don't want to do it. I need to read the clientId while I receive the request
    });
})
```

Let's assume that we made a middleware and a request came out

```
public RequestMiddleware(){
   //Here I need to inject some service
}

//Invoke method of middleware
public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next){
  HttpRequestData requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();
  requestData.Headers.TryGetValues("client-id", out var clientId);
  var id = clientId.First();
  //And here, I need to configure App Configuration to use the id as a label. As I did in the Program.cs
 //like this ; options.Select(KeyFilter.Any, id);
}
```

Does it possible to load configuration by the label in the request lifecycle? Please keep in mind that Azure App Configuration in the standard tier has a limitation on requests, 3000 per hour. That's why it won't be a good idea to load AppConfiguration each time.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is work with a static Dictionary to 'cache' and whenever a request with some new client id arrives, you fetch the configuration add it to the dictionary for the future requests.

Comment: I'm coding an Azure Function. I won't be able to get data from a static dictionary at the next time. Because the application itself is stateless. Function context may restart at any time. Am I wrong?

Comment: no, static Dictionaries will be shared among function instances https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections?tabs=csharp#static-clients

Answer (score 0):

This document discussed strategies you should think about when using App Configuration in multi-tenant applications.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/service/app-configuration

From your description, it looks like you want to load tenant-specific config on-demand instead of all at once at the app startup, so you shouldn't need the code in program.cs. I would recommend using prefixes instead of labels to differentiate the config date for each tenant.

Check out the [application-side caching section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/guide/multitenant/service/app-configuration#application-side-caching) to learn more what options you have. I imagine, in the middleware, upon every request, you will first check if you have a cached `IConfiguration` instance for the tenant; if not, you will load the config for this tenant and cache it; if yes, you serve the request based on the config in your cache.